# Fetching the list of users who have permission to use SharePoint page

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, user, xpath

When using `_api/web/siteusers?` I get a lot of usernames and email adresses.

With XPath I managed to filter them.

Then I realized that there were a huge amount of usernames and email adresses who don't have access to my page.

In SharePoint theREST API `/_api/web/siteusers` endpoint only provides the list of users has permission on current web.

How can I fetch the users who have the permission to use my Sharepoint page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of you need to see permissions on the web you can simply

- Navigate to the web permissions page (`http://XXX/_layouts/15/user.aspx`)

In case of you need to see permissions to particular site page try the following

- Open site pages library
- Select page
- Click on `Shared with` - `Advanced`

Answer (score 2):

to get permissions on SharePoint page by SP rest Api You may use the fallowing request:

```
.../_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('[RELATIVE URL OF PAGE]')?$expand=ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users
```

where the relative url of the page would of a page like:
https://SomeSharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/test2/SitePages/test1.aspx
will be /sites/test2/SitePages/test1.aspx and the request would look like

```
https://SomeSharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/test2/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test2/SitePages/test1.aspx')?$expand=ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot!!